# C# asp.net error when trying to parse json from a file using JObject

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
JObject configInfo = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("config.json"));

const string ServerName = (string)configInfo["servername"];
```

Seems simple enough, but I keep getting this error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'AdminTools_Admin_ManageElements.configInfo'

Can someone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: You can't set a constant to something not hardcoded like that.

Comment: @mason when I get rid of const the errors still appears

Comment: Okay, fine. What about the error don't you understand then? Likely you should be setting the value for server name in a constructor or initializer method, rather than inline with your field declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error implies that you're doing this at the *class level* as part of initializing fields in that class:

```
class SomeClass
{
    JObject configInfo = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("config.json"));

    const string ServerName = (string)configInfo["servername"];
}
```

What the error is telling you is that you can't initialize fields depending on the initialization of other fields like this.  (And you *certainly* can't create a constant from a runtime-dynamic value.)

This would be something to do inside of a method instead.  Potential arguments against reading from a file in a constructor aside for a moment, consider something like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    JObject configInfo;
    string ServerName;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        configInfo = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("config.json"));
        ServerName = (string)configInfo["servername"];
    }
}
```

Basically, you're trying to put too much dynamic logic in the *definition* of the class where that logic needs to happen in the *operations* of the class.  The definition is just structure.  Things like parsing input and dynamically setting values happen in methods.